# Setbuf(stdout, 0) and fflush don't work

Tags: c, printf, buffer, posix

For some strange reason

```
setbuf(stdout, 0);
```

worked in my case only if i used in the parent process.

I need my child process  to read from a pipe and write the data into a file; I redirected STDIN_FILENO and STDOUT_FILENO to the coresponding files;

Must mention that the reading process looks like this :

```
void read_from_pipe(void)
{
    char command[100];

    int new_fd = open(pipe_name,O_RDONLY,0644);
    int output_file = open("new_file",O_WRONLY|O_CREAT,0644);

    dup2(new_fd,STDIN_FILENO);
    dup2(output_file,STDOUT_FILENO);

    while(1)
    {   
        scanf("%s",command);

        if(strcmp(command,"stop")==0)
        {
            close(output_file);
            close(new_fd);
            exit(0);
        }
        else
            {
                printf("%s ",command);
                fflush(stdout);
            }
    }
}
```

The problem is that if i do CTRL-C the child process doesn't write any data into the output file?

I tried forcing it with fflush(stdin);

It didin't work;

I tried using setbuf(stdout,0); in the child process, it didin't work either;

The only solution that i found was writing

```
setbuf(stdout, 0);
```

in the parent process;

Could someone explain why it worked only if written in the parent process?

Thank you!

Later EDIT:

I tried the following code :

Could it be something OS related? ( I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS )

Comment: Why does everyone use `scanf` for reading simple strings? Hint: Use `read`.

Comment: You can only usefully use `setbuf()` before anything is written to the stream.

Comment: @tadman If i use read, i won't be making use of dup2. I could directly read from the file descriptos. I prefer usingt scanf. This is solely for learning purposes.

Comment: You don't show more than one process, so its impossible to say, but the FILE buffers in each process are indepedent, so you need to do the `setbuf` or `fflush` in the process that does the `printf`s that are writing to the FILE -- doing it in another process will only affect that other process.

Comment: I get that you're learning but I honestly have no idea why you're calling `dup2` at all.

Comment: To redirect printf towards a certain file

Comment: @Eduard6421don't you know `fprintf`?